# Java method isn't calledin expression

Tags: java, jar

I really confused about this issue, I have a method that returns boolean - mainMethod(), so I use the result in logical expression, see here:

```
    boolean b = this.someMethod(); 
    b = b && this.mainMethod(); // method is not called
```

I checked jar file via decompiler everything is OK. Then I changed the lines above to:

```
  boolean b = this.someMethod(); 
  boolean result = this.mainMethod(); // now method is called!!!
  b = b && result;
```

Does anywone know how this might happen? I have no idea, this is looking very strange.

Comment: If `b` is already `false` in the first example it won't continue past `&&`.

Comment: You can use the bitwise operator `&` to avoid short-circuiting. You can avoid bugs like this by making your code self-documenting. None of us know what it means for `mainMethod()` to return `true` or `false`. If you had assigned it to a variable like `boolean ranSuccessfully`, then you would have avoided the bug and it would be clear what your code is doing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If `this.someMethod()` returns `false` then `this.mainMethod()` will never be invoked due to the short circuit nature of the `&&` operator in the statement

```
b = b && this.mainMethod();
```

Answer (score 0):

`&&` is the [conditional and operator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.23). In the expression

```
a && b
```

if `a` is `false`, `b` won't be evaluated because the whole expression will evaluate to `false`. `b` is only evaluated if `a` is `true`.

So what's happening is that `someMethod` is returning `false`; `mainMethod` then isn't executed because it's known that the whole expression will evaluate to `false`, irrespective of the value returned from `mainMethod`.

Answer (score 0):

If "b" is already false, it is not necessary to evaluate the second expression:

```
true AND ? <= ? must be evaluated
false AND ? <= = must not be evaluated as

false AND true => false
false AND false => false
```

so it doesnt matter what the second expression evaluates to.

Answer (score 0):

The previous answers are correct.  There is a short circuit nature.

```
false && method()
```

Will never execute method() because the boolean already is false so there is nothing that can possibly make the value return true.  In this case you are looking to assign a boolean value so it will stop evaluating the statement.

If you need to evaluate both methods and still have the boolean result returned you need to execute the code one of the following ways:

```
boolean b = methodA();
b &= methodB();
```

or

```
boolean b = methodA();
b = methodB() && b;
```